# Workaround for lack of broadcast in TFLite

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to run a TFLite model that requires me to produce a 3d output (the sample code is a minimum example generating the error). Is there a tensorflow equivalent to gather_nd that does not reduce the dimension by one?

I've tried looking through the documentation for related functions that I can think of and haven't found a good option.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
import numpy as np

tf.disable_v2_behavior()
initial_input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None,5,1024))
cap_i = tf.gather_nd(initial_input, [[0,1]]) #[0,2],[0,3],[0,4],[0,5]
cap_i_broadcast = tf.broadcast_to(cap_i, [1,5,1024])
cap_iT = tf.transpose(cap_i_broadcast, perm=[0,2,1])

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
tf.io.write_graph(sess.graph_def, '', 'train.pbtxt')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_session(sess, [initial_input], [cap_iT])
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open('converted_model.tflite', "wb").write(tflite_model)
sess.close()
```

Some of the operators in the model are not supported by the standard TensorFlow Lite runtime and are not recognized by TensorFlow. If you have a custom implementation for them you can disable this error with --allow_custom_ops, or by setting allow_custom_ops=True when calling tf.lite.TFLiteConverter(). Here is a list of builtin operators you are using: GATHER_ND, TRANSPOSE. Here is a list of operators for which you will need custom implementations: BroadcastTo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code has a solution using strided slice with dimensionality reduction and then reshape to get back the correct dimension.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
import numpy as np

tf.disable_v2_behavior()
initial_input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None,5,1024))
cap_i = tf.strided_slice(initial_input, [0,0,0], [0,5,1024], [1,1,1], 
shrink_axis_mask=1)
cap_i_reshaped =tf.reshape(cap_i,[1,5,1024])
cap_iT = tf.transpose(cap_i_reshaped, perm=[0,2,1])

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
tf.io.write_graph(sess.graph_def, '', 'train.pbtxt')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_session(sess, [initial_input], 
[cap_iT])
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, 
tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open('converted_model.tflite', "wb").write(tflite_model)
sess.close()
```

Previously thought slice was supported in TFLite but only strided_slice is.